# Summarize Daily working events without including time from the next dates activity in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with a log of daily events:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFp4g.png)

and a related date table

I would like to be able to sum up the total time of events that happen within each given date. The output would look like this:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YeTT.png)

Is there a simple way of doing this with dax? I have done it in the past with multiple calculated columns and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Please provide your sample data in copy-able format, not png.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using **calculated tables**:

1. Split your overnight shifts into daily chunks
2. Aggregate the results

```
Split work per date = 
VAR thisdate  =  
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        'Work',
        "Date", DATEVALUE('Work'[Start Datetime]),
        "Minutes", 
            IF( DATEVALUE('Work'[Start Datetime]) <> DATEVALUE('Work'[End Datetime]),
                ROUND((DATEVALUE('Work'[End Datetime]) - 'Work'[Start Datetime]) * 24 * 60, 0),
                ROUND(('Work'[End Datetime] - 'Work'[Start Datetime]) * 24 * 60, 0) ) )
VAR nextdate = 
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        'Work',
        "Date", DATEVALUE('Work'[Start Datetime]) + 1,
        "Minutes", 
            IF( DATEVALUE('Work'[Start Datetime]) <> DATEVALUE('Work'[End Datetime]),
                ROUND(('Work'[End Datetime] - DATEVALUE('Work'[End Datetime])) * 24 * 60, 0),
                0 ) )
RETURN
    UNION( thisdate, nextdate)
```

Power BI can already aggregate 'Split work per date'[Date] and 'Split work per date'[Minutes] in a table visual:

[image]

But you can also do this "manually" in another table:

```
Summarize work per date = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Split work per date',
    'Split work per date'[Date],
    "Minutes", SUM('Split work per date'[Minutes])
)
```

[image]

Comment: So that does not quite add up to what I am seeking. The result that provides adds up what events started on each day not the elapsed time of the events on each day. See picture 2 for what would need to be output. 

This Is what I currently have:

Over midnight Indicator = if('Work'[Start Date]<>'Work'[End Date],1,0)

Before Midnight = Round(if('Work'[Over midnight Indicator]=0,
    'Work'[Working Time Minutes],
        ('Work'[End Date]-'Work'[Start Datetime])*24*60),0)

These are three separate columns, this works. But is there a good way to do something like that with less 'work'

Comment: What do you mean with "less work" - your work or mine work? I understand that you don't find my answer useful, but now you need to specify further conditions to your initial question?

Comment: Less work would mean not using any more than one additional calculated column, It's a large database and I'm trying to see if there is anything built in to dax that would make this calculation more simple. It seems like a common issue that someone would have run in to before. If there is not, that is fine.

Comment: I updated the solution without using any calculated columns.